# Flutter webview_flutter Localization

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, webview-flutter

How to change the language of copying/cutting?

The following code has been added to the main file, but it does not take effect in WebViewWidget

```
localizationsDelegates: const [
              RefreshLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate()
            ],
            locale: const Locale('zh'),
            supportedLocales: const [
              Locale('zh', 'CN'),
            ]localizationsDelegates: const [
              RefreshLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate()
            ],
            locale: const Locale('zh'),
            supportedLocales: const [
              Locale('zh', 'CN'),
            ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDIWP.jpg)